# Is there a builtin c# class to define time-window that has start date and end date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetimeoffset

Is there a suitable c# class in regards to define a time-window that I can use to set a start date and end date?

Comment: Nothing in the framework, but there are third-party classes out there.

Comment: An alternative with framework classes would be `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>`

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can easily create a struct that holds a DateTime and TimeSpan... Should be just a few lines of code...

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187028/sliding-window-algorithm-in-c-sharp

Comment: Rephrasing: you need start `DateTime` and end `DateTime` is the same as asking for any other 2 of basic data types (e.g. start `int`, end `int`.. or start `string` and end `string`). You can use any collection to hold multiple items (`DateTime[]`). But the best is to simply create own [`struct` or `class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) and add properties and useful methods to it (consider overriding `ToString()`).

Comment: FYI - The reason nothing is built in is that different implementations have different concerns.  `DateTime` is used in a few different scenarios, depending on whether you take the whole value into account or just examine the date or time portions, and also depending on the value of the `.Kind` property.   It would be difficult to create a single `DateTimeRange` object that fits all scenarios.  Instead one would need a variety of specialized objects.  You can always create your own object that fits your particular specialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in the framework, but some alternatives would be:

- `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>` - would not have any built-in date functionality but would store your data
- `Tuple<DateTime, TimeSpan>` - if start date and duration better meets your needs
- custom class - simple class with two properties - you could then build date functions within it to meet your needs
- Third-party libraries - search for ".NET date library" - I'm sure you'll find something that has some sort of `Interval` class that may help.

Comment: FWIW - [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) has an `Interval` type which is a half-open range of `Instant` values.